# How do I completely ignore a wireless connection?

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, airport, preferences

I've removed a wifi ssid from the remembered connections list, but I would like to go one further and disable it from appearing in the wifi drop down list (after clicking on the wireless icon on the menu bar).

Can this be done? I don't want the computer user to be able to click it and switch to it again (this particular connection doesn't require a password and it is not connected to the internet). Thanks!

Comment: Are these SSIDs under your, (or your organization's,) control?